# Swift: Update UIView using multipeer connectivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, multipeer-connectivity

I am writing an app using multipeer connectivity framework. One of my device will prepare a list of UIView items and send to the other device. When the other device receive the list, it place it on the view and display.

However, I found that the device can receive the list, and can print out the frames of each of the items inside the list. However, it place it on the screen with a for loop, but the view never get updated. Any idea on what I missed?

```
func placeViews() {
    for (string, item) in self.imageViewItemViews {
      debugPrint(string, item.frame) // print out what it received correctly
      self.containerView.addSubview(item)
    }
  }
```

containerView is already displaying when the app is launched. I have also called self.containerView.setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: you can check all subviews when application is running using Debug view hierarchy (3D view). I attached image for the same in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may possible sub views are back in Hierarchy of views. you can even check this with **Debug view hierarchy** (3D view) as per below image.

[image: Debug view hierarchy]

If your view are back of the main view you can use this code, even you don't know about superView:

**In objective-c:**

```
[subview.superview bringSubviewToFront: subview];
```

**In swift:**

```
subview.superview.bringSubviewToFront(subview)
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Though it still cannot solve my problem, you let me know there is such debug mode and I can use it in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @user6539552 Good you solved your own issue and my answer will help you in future debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that it is because my code are not executed at the main thread, and hence it does not update the UI.